# How to create memory region/section with following properties (checked by QueryWorkingSetEx and VirtualQuery)?

Tags: winapi, memory, memory-management, paging

I need to make memory region/section with following properties:

`VirtualQuery` function checked on such region should return:

- AllocationProtect: 0x20 [`PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`]
- Protect: 0x20 [`PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`]
- State: 0x1000 [`MEM_COMMIT`]
- Type: 0x40000 [`MAPPED`]

`QueryWorkingSetEx` function checked on such region should return:

- Valid: 1
- Shared: 1
- ShareCount: 2
- Node: 0
- LargePage: 0
- Locked: 0
- Bad: 0
- Win32Protection: 0x20 [`PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`]

Additionally, this region cannot be mapped to disk file (`INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` when creating mapped file section). Also it should be filled with desired data before it comes with only `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` access.

Moreover, it's not possible to change protection of such sector (using `VirtualProtect` function) to `PAGE_READONLY` or `PAGE_WRITECOPY`, despite it's `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`. It indicates that it could have undocumented SEC_NO_CHANGE property.

It's possible to do it because it exists in a malware that I am debugging, but it's difficult for me to replicate, also few people in a team failed, I will be impressed if someone will provide me with information about how to create it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here nothing hard todo - we really need create section with

```
#define SEC_NO_CHANGE 0x00400000
```

from [*createsec.c*](https://github.com/bigzz/WRK/blob/master/base/ntos/mm/creasect.c#L204)

> `SEC_NO_CHANGE` - Once the file is mapped, the protection cannot
>                   be changed nor can the view be unmapped.  The
>                   view is unmapped when the process is deleted.
>                   Cannot be used with `SEC_IMAGE`.

so need simply create section with this flag. then first map it with `PAGE_READWRITE` page protection and init it data. than unmap and map again with `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` protection. all. nothing special or hard.

```
#define SEC_NO_CHANGE 0x00400000

NTSTATUS ghty(PVOID* pBaseAddress, ULONG SectionSize = 0x10000)
{
    HANDLE hSection;
    LARGE_INTEGER MaxSize = { SectionSize };
    NTSTATUS status = ZwCreateSection(&hSection, 
        SECTION_MAP_READ|SECTION_MAP_WRITE|SECTION_MAP_EXECUTE, 0, &MaxSize, 
        PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, SEC_COMMIT|SEC_NO_CHANGE, 0);

    if (0 <= status)
    {
        PVOID BaseAddress = 0;
        SIZE_T ViewSize = 0;

        if (0 <= (status = ZwMapViewOfSection(hSection, NtCurrentProcess(), 
            &BaseAddress, 0, 0, 0, &ViewSize, ViewUnmap, 0, PAGE_READWRITE)))
        {

            memset(BaseAddress, 0xc3, ViewSize);
            ZwUnmapViewOfSection(NtCurrentProcess(), BaseAddress);

            *pBaseAddress = 0;
            status = ZwMapViewOfSection(hSection, NtCurrentProcess(), 
                pBaseAddress, 0, 0, 0, &(ViewSize = 0), ViewUnmap, 0, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ);
        }

        NtClose(hSection);
    }

    return status;
}

void test()
{
    PVOID BaseAddress;
    if (0 <= ghty(&BaseAddress))
    {
        //++ test
        ULONG op;
        SIZE_T Size = 1;
        PVOID pv = BaseAddress;
        ZwProtectVirtualMemory(NtCurrentProcess(), &pv, &Size, PAGE_READONLY, &op);
        // STATUS_INVALID_PAGE_PROTECTION will be
        // if we use SEC_NO_CHANGE
        // -- test

        ZwUnmapViewOfSection(NtCurrentProcess(), BaseAddress);
    }
}
```

also just found this link [*Self-Remapping Code*](https://github.com/changeofpace/Self-Remapping-Code). possible code which you debug do the same. think sense do this - you can not set breakpoints (int 3) in this code - because memory not writable and can not be maked writable. as result impossible insert bp

Comment: The problem is sector created using your method have not the same properties I wrote in the question. ShareCount is 0 instead of 2. Locked is 1 instead of 0. Win32Protection returned from QueryWorkingSetEx is 0 instead of 32.

Comment: @Vuklan *Win32Protection returned from QueryWorkingSetEx is 0* - this can not be. you wrong check. ShareCount \Locked - this is internal values at all. more than 1 `ShareCount` mean that section mapped in else process. unclear what you want.

Comment: @Vuklan - i sure your error that you not check `Valid` flag in `PSAPI_WORKING_SET_EX_BLOCK` and it 0 - mean that now page not in memory and all another members in this case not valid too. if want page to be locked - call `VirtualLock(BaseAddress, 1);` on this address. after this you view protection 32 (`PAGE_EXECUTE_READ`) on page and `Locked == 1`. but for make `ShareCount ==2` need map this section to else one process

Comment: Malware detects such remap somehow and shutdowns itself after few seconds. I was thinking it is maybe of different values using QueryWorkingSetEx(that's why I wanted it return the same), but maybe it checks it in some different way.

Comment: memory region which i create in demo of course have `PAGE_EXECUTE_READ` protection. if you want it to be locked - call `VirtualLock(BaseAddress, *)` after `ghty` return. but i not understand now your question - what you really want view in answer

Comment: Thanks. Yes It was about "Valid" flag, it wasn't in a memory yet. Now it's ok. However malware detects such remap of its main code region after few seconds, in a way I don't know yet.

Comment: How can I map this section in another process, so ShareCount will show 2? - Maybe it's the way it is detected.

Comment: @Vuklan - really not mandatory to another process. my mistake. simply map section more than once. say in current code - comment  `ZwUnmapViewOfSection`. of call `ZwMapViewOfSection` else one. `ShareCount` - this is count of section maps. what more than 1 - map section more than once.